# Could not make a call on api on heroku

Tags: maven, heroku, dropwizard

I have deployed my dropwizard application on heroku. https://github.com/shabyWoks/DropWizardProjectStarter But after deploying the app i cannot see my api service taking my call from browser. I have attached the project to github and link is attached here. I am new in the face of application deployment on server and could not figure out what is happening.
Can anyoune help me?

Comment: how do you run your jar. where's the yaml file?

Comment: Thanks for answering.. but I found the answer.